# What are the downsides of calling shell script from EJB?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Our business case needs us to call a shell script from a Message Bean. Other than the obvious portability issues, and the standards compliance, what is the problem with calling a shell script from a bean? Technically speaking, the container, WebLogic, will allow me to, but it sure seems like a bad practice. What would a good alternative be? It is a synchronous call in this case.

Comment: Could you tell us what the shell script does?

Comment: One does a PS looking for a process, and one uses Awk/Sed to modify a flat file. Both are dependent on the JMS message content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Other than the obvious portability issues, and the standards compliance, what is the problem with calling a shell script from a bean?

You have covered the most important ones.

The only others I can think of are:

- the engineering issues of maintaining a "mixed" solution
- potential performance issues; e.g. if the task could be done significantly faster if coded in Java and (typically) run in the main JVM.

> Technically speaking, the container, WebLogic, will allow me to, but it sure seems like a bad practice.

Bad practice should not be equated with inelegance.  Good / bad practice is about things that will / would have a measurable impact according to some objective criterion ... if you could measure them.

> What would a good alternative be? It is a synchronous call in this case.

The general alternative is to code the task in Java.  You should be able to do that in the `awk`/`sed` case.  In the case where you are using `ps` to look for an external process, you probably can't do the task at all in pure Java, and that means that your current approach is best.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's okay, we use it all the time. Mind that the bean would be busy waiting for the synchronous call, so if you don't have enough free beans for the load the queue would stall.

Answer (score 0):

@Stephen C: Nice response.

The issue & responses leads my thoughts toward resource management: consider the resources the external processes will be accessing.

If the resources are:

- strictly "computational" (awk/sed over stdin/stdout), this is a not unreasonable way to leverage existing tools (in the spirit of UNIX) to rip out a quick solution - however it's non-portable.  If I were prototyping, or under a rapid development schedule, I'd give this some consideration, leaning towards this only for more complex problems.
- files, networks, etc then thought should be given to how those resources *should* be managed in a scale-able Java EE environment.
- processes, for the purpose of process management - not otherwise available to Java/Java EE, as in the case of `ps`/processes, turning towards the O/S is required.
- processes/threads for the purpose of parallelizing work - don't be tempted to manage parallel workflow.. Java EE *does* have scale-able APIs for that purpose.